# Access anonymous Runnable instance in Mockito / Powermock

Tags: java, mockito, runnable, powermock

This is my test code:

```
Activity activityMock = Mockito.mock(TestActivity.class);    

doAnswer(new Answer() {
     @Override
     public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
     Object[] args = invocationOnMock.getArguments(); // ->>>> args contains one Foo instance called "foo"
     return invocationOnMock;
  }
}).when(activityMock).runOnUiThread(any(Runnable.class));

runDialogOnUiThread(activityMock, new Foo());
```

To the following production code:

```
public static void runDialogOnUIThread(final Activity activity, final Foo foo) {
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            doSmth();
        }
    });
}
```

See my comment in the test code. I expect invocationOnMock.getArguments() to return the Runnable instance, but it is returning the Foo instance (Which makes absolutely no sense to me)?

I thought

```
doAnswer(new Answer(){..}).when(b).bMethod(any(C.class))
```

intercepts when bMethod() is called anywhere on b and it will pass the instance of C.class to the doAnswer() to make it available in the "new Answer().."-Callback..

How can I access the anonymous Runnable instance, which is created in the production code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your anonymous `Runnable` instance is defined in `Foo`, right?

Here's some code I wrote to try to reproduce your issue:

```
public class MockitoTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final Activity activityMock = Mockito.mock(TestActivity.class);

        doAnswer(new Answer() {
             @Override
             public Object answer(final InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
                 final Object[] args = invocationOnMock.getArguments();
                 System.out.println("Is argument a Runnable? " + (args[0] instanceof Runnable));
                 System.out.println("What is the argument toString()? " + args[0].toString());
                 return invocationOnMock;
             }
        }).when(activityMock).runOnUiThread(any(Runnable.class));

        runDialogOnUIThread(activityMock);
    }


    public void runDialogOnUIThread(final Activity activity) {
        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                System.out.println("***");
            }};
        activity.runOnUiThread(r);
    }

    public static interface Activity {
        void runOnUiThread(Runnable r);
    }

    public static class TestActivity implements Activity {
        @Override
        public void runOnUiThread(final Runnable r) { r.run(); }
    }

}
```

Pretty much the same thing, but it is trimmed down to illustrate where I think you are getting confused.

The output is:

```
Is argument a Runnable? true
What is the argument toString()? stackoverflow.MockitoTest$2@6b143ee9
```

Note that the second output contains `MockitoTest` for the `toString()` output and nothing about it being a `Runnable`. That's because the `toString()` method is not being explicitly defined in the anonymous `Runnable`.

Let's change the `Runnable` as follows:

```
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            System.out.println("***");
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            return "ANON RUNNABLE";
        }
    };
```

Then the output is:

```
Is argument a Runnable? true
What is the argument toString()? ANON RUNNABLE
```

What I suspect you were getting tripped up on is that the toString() output looked like the same class name as the class that the anonymous `Runnable` was created in.